# GCE Windows Startup script failing with parsing errors

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I have a PowerShell script in one of the GCS buckets. I configured a GCE instance to use this as the startup script. This GCE instance has service accounts and has the necessary API access. However, when the script starts running, I see parsing errors. I can run the script locally without any issues. This happens only when I use that from a GCS bucket. If I put the script as a Github gist, it runs perfectly as well.

Here is what I see in the serial console log.

`2018/02/27 18:08:25 GCEMetadataScripts: Starting startup scripts (version 4.1.6@1).
2018/02/27 18:08:42 GCEMetadataScripts: Found windows-startup-script-url in metadata.
2018/02/27 18:10:09 windows-startup-script-url: At C:\Windows\TEMP\metadata-scripts968189735\windows-startup-script-url.ps1:2 
2018/02/27 18:10:09 windows-startup-script-url: char:9
2018/02/27 18:10:09 windows-startup-script-url: +  "error": {
2018/02/27 18:10:09 windows-startup-script-url: +         ~
2018/02/27 18:10:09 windows-startup-script-url: Unexpected token ':' in expression or statement.
2018/02/27 18:10:09 windows-startup-script-url: At C:\Windows\TEMP\metadata-scripts968189735\windows-startup-script-url.ps1:3 
2018/02/27 18:10:09 windows-startup-script-url: char:11
2018/02/27 18:10:09 windows-startup-script-url: +   "errors": [
2018/02/27 18:10:09 windows-startup-script-url: +           ~
2018/02/27 18:10:09 windows-startup-script-url: Unexpected token ':' in expression or statement.
2018/02/27 18:10:09 windows-startup-script-url: At C:\Windows\TEMP\metadata-scripts968189735\windows-startup-script-url.ps1:5 
2018/02/27 18:10:09 windows-startup-script-url: char:13
2018/02/27 18:10:09 windows-startup-script-url: +     "domain": "global",
2018/02/27 18:10:09 windows-startup-script-url: +             ~
2018/02/27 18:10:09 windows-startup-script-url: Unexpected token ':' in expression or statement.
2018/02/27 18:10:09 windows-startup-script-url: At C:\Windows\TEMP\metadata-scripts968189735\windows-startup-script-url.ps1:11 
2018/02/27 18:10:10 windows-startup-script-url: char:4
2018/02/27 18:10:10 windows-startup-script-url: +   ],
2018/02/27 18:10:10 windows-startup-script-url: +    ~
2018/02/27 18:10:10 windows-startup-script-url: Missing argument in parameter list.
2018/02/27 18:10:10 windows-startup-script-url:     + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx 
2018/02/27 18:10:10 windows-startup-script-url:    ception
2018/02/27 18:10:10 windows-startup-script-url:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
2018/02/27 18:10:10 windows-startup-script-url:

2018/02/27 18:10:10 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url exit status 1
2018/02/27 18:10:10 GCEMetadataScripts: Finished running startup scripts.`

Here is the startup script.

```
[DscLocalConfigurationManager()]
Configuration GCEDscMetaConfig
{

    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [String]
        $RegistrationUrl,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
        [String]
        $RegistrationKey,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [String[]]
        $ConfigurationNames

    )

    Node localhost
    {

        Settings
        {
            RefreshMode = 'Pull'
        }

        ConfigurationRepositoryWeb AzureAutomationDSC
        {
            ServerUrl = $RegistrationUrl
            RegistrationKey = $RegistrationKey
            ConfigurationNames = $ConfigurationNames
        }

        ResourceRepositoryWeb AzureAutomationDSC
        {
            ServerUrl = $RegistrationUrl
            RegistrationKey = $RegistrationKey
        }

        ReportServerWeb AzureAutomationDSC
        {
            ServerUrl = $RegistrationUrl
            RegistrationKey = $RegistrationKey
        }
    }
}

$Params = @{
    RegistrationUrl    = 'https://pullserver/accounts/7471b7ce-95d2-4766-be97-221f4d33f56a'
    RegistrationKey    = 'ljey=='
    ConfigurationNames = 'webserver.localhost'
    OutputPath         = "$env:TEMP\MetaConfig"
}

GCEDscMetaConfig @Params

Set-DscLocalConfigurationManager -Path "$env:TEMP\MetaConfig" -Verbose
```

This is just a DSC meta configuration script.

Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: Is it possible to provide the startup script? This will help to find out whether there is any change required to be done on the script itself.

Comment: I updated the question with the script that I am trying to use as a startup script. This is just a DSC meta configuration script that will compile and enact DSC LCM configuration.

Comment: Have you followed the instructions for startup script kept in GCS bucket as [stated here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#providing_a_startup_script)? If you have, which windows image are you using?